# Scala case class: avoid recomputation of the property

Tags: scala

I am asking this because I have encountered this use case many times.

Let's say we have a case class like this:

```
case class C(xs: Iterable[Int]) {
    val max = xs.max

    def ++(that: C) = C(xs ++ that.xs)
}
```

This works fine, but the `++` operation is inefficient, since the collection is needlessly traversed once more to compute the maximum of the result; since we already know the maximums of both collections, we could reuse that - by using something like this:

```
def ++(that: C) =
    C(xs ++ that.xs, max = math.max(max, that.max))
```

This is just a simple example to demonstrate the purpose - the computation avoided could be a lot more complex, or maybe even a TCP data fetch.

How to avoid this recomputation (see the second code snippet), keeping the code elegant?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I thought that was obvious, but there you have it. @m-z: You are exactly right. However, this is just a really basic case.

Comment: @RokKralj I've edited my answer, now it also ensures correctness of C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case class C(xs: Iterable[Int]) {
  private var maxOp = Option.empty[Int]

  lazy val max = maxOp getOrElse {
    maxOp = Some(xs.max)
    maxOp.get
  }

  def ++(that: C) = {
    val res = C(xs ++ that.xs)
    res.maxOp = Some(math.max(this.max, that.max))
    res
  }
}
```

Comment: Apart from a few code style pitfalls (I am going to make an edit), I like this solution the most.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work

```
class C private (val xs: Iterable[Int], val max: Int) {        

    def ++(that: C) = new C(xs ++ that.xs, math.max(this.max, that.max)
}

object C {
    def apply(xs: Iterable[Int]) = new C(xs, xs.max)
}
```

Note that C is no longer a case class to avoid max and xs becoming inconsistent. If C was a case class, you could call e.g. c.copy(max = -1) and get an inconsistent instance.

Comment: Inconsistency, good point! I took the freedom to ensure consistency in my answer as well

Comment: I like this answer, but this way, you lose ALL the benefits of a case class, such as hashCode.

Comment: Restore case class and define a copy method on C to disable the default copy method.

Comment: You could also have `case class C private (xs: Iterable[Int])(val max: Int)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you would still have a copy method that you would have to make safe or disable. Otherwise you could do `val c = C(Seq(1,2,3)); c.copy()(-1)`. I think that case classes are for pure data. As soon as you do something tricky like having multiple things that have to be consistent with each other, it is better to write your apply and unapply yourself even if it is more code.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn Oops, you are right. I just assumed argument lists after the first aren't handled by `copy` (just as for `equals` and `hashCode`), but of course you could still change `xs` and it would make it just as inconsistent!

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov actually, the copy method will have the exact same shape as the apply method. A case class with multiple argument lists will also have a copy method with multiple argument lists. If you want a case class that contains non-essential state that is not a val or lazy val, multiple argument lists are one way to go. But I think you should keep non-essential state out of your domain model completely, and attach it by means of memoization if it is needed for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since `max` is already a `val` (in contrast to a method) you could do it this way:

```
case class C private (xs: Iterable[Int], max: Int) {
  def ++(that: C) = C(xs ++ that.xs, math.max(max, that.max))

  def copy(_xs: Iterable[Int] = this.xs) = {
    if (_xs == this.xs) {
      C(xs, max)
    } else {
      C(_xs)
    }
  }
}

object C {
  def apply(xs: Iterable[Int]): C = C(xs, xs.max)
}
```

If you are going to pattern match on this case class, then it depends on your use cases, if you can (or must) pattern match on `max` as well.

*Update 1* As pointed out by Rüdiger I have added `private` to the constructor so that `xs` and `max` are consistent.

*Update 2* As pointed out by som-snytt, the `copy` method must be handled as well to to prevent inconsistency.

Comment: This doesn't address the copy method problem. But (by the spec) you can define copy on class C and override the default behavior.

Comment: @som-snytt OK, added a fix for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
sealed trait C {
  val xs: Iterable[Int]
  val max: Int

  def ++(that: C) = ComposedC(this, that)
}

case class ValidatedC(xs: Iterable[Int]) extends C {
  val max = xs.max
}

case class ComposedC(a: C, b: C) extends C {
  val max = math.max(a.max, b.max)
  val xs = a.xs ++ b.xs
}

object C {
  def apply(xs: Iterable[Int]) = ValidatedC(xs)
}
```

A simpler solution (which doesn't enforce correctness) - 
Introduce a way to provide pre-computed `max` and an auxiliary constructor that gets 2 Cs.

```
case class C(xs: Iterable[Int])(val max: Int = xs.max) {
  def this(a: C, b: C) = {
    this(a.xs ++ b.xs)(math.max(a.max, b.max))
  }

  def ++(that: C) = new C(this, that)
}
```